# stat_summary: posthoc labels for boxplot using separate dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a boxplot with posthoc labels from a vector (`CLD.gm2.lf.group`) over each boxplot using the below code.

The vector is ordered how I would like my labels to appear across the boxplots, but `stat_summary` seems to jumble the order of the labels on the plot.

For example, my vector, ordered in how I want it across the plot:

```
CLD.gm2.lf.group
[1] " a"  " a"  " a"  " a " " ab" "  b" " ab" "  b" " a " " a"  " a"  " a"  " a"  " a" 
[15] " a"  " a"  " a"  " a"  " a"  " a"  " a"
```

The boxplot from the below code:

[image]

```
ggplot(Total.Grad, aes(x, y, fill = treatment)) +
 geom_boxplot(aes(fill = treatment)) +
 theme_light() +
 ylim(5,28) +
 scale_fill_brewer(palette = "YlGnBu") +
 stat_summary(geom = 'text',
              size = 3,
              label = CLD.gm2.lf.group,
              fun.y = max,
              vjust = -1,
              position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))
```

As you can see, it consistently flips 'Minimal' and 'Extensive'. It is not alphabetical. Why would it jumble a vector in such a specific way, instead of pasting it regularly across the plot?

Comment: Can't tell without seeing your data, but my first guess is it's an issue of the fact that labels are coming in from a vector that isn't connected to the main dataframe `ggplot` is using, so there's probably something going on with factors that aren't ordered the way you want. I'd really really recommend having the labels as a column in your dataframe.